# Why is my EEPROM not working?

Tags: stm32, i2c, eeprom, error

I have a [24FC01](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/24AA0-24LC01B-24FC01-Data-Sheet-20001711L.pdf), 1 kbit EEPROM on my board. The SDA and SCL lines are pulled up to 3.3V through two 2k resistors. I'm using a STM32F407 MCU to read and write data to the EEPROM. Using the HAL libraries, I'm trying to check if the device is ready using `HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&i2c2, 0x50, 2, 100)` function. However, this fails and returns false. The I2C is configured in `CubeMX` with 100 kHz clock speed and 7-bit addressing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The STM32 HAL uses 8-bit addresses. Use 0xA0.

Answer (score 3):

From the HAL source code:

> DevAddress Target device address: The device 7 bits
> address value  in datasheet must be shifted to the left
> before calling the interface

n.b. shifted to the left by one bit.